# Number of preceeding words before a phrase in a string

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have a list of phrases:

```
list = ['new york', 'school', 'new']
```

and a string

```
text = 'i am going to a school in new york and therefore i have to buy a new uniform to go to new york'
```

I would like to find the number of words preceeding each phrase (just for first appearance) ie output should be:

```
new york = 7
school = 5
new = 7
```

Any idea how I can effectively achieve this?

Comment: First you'd need something to tokenize your `text` and the elements of your `list`. Are your using some function/module as tokenizer?

Comment: SHould new not be 7 as well?

Comment: No I am just splitting the text on spaces

Comment: Yes it should be 7 I fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach, without any performance or NLP considerations:

```
lst = ['new york', 'school', 'new']  # do not use 'list' as a name
text = 'i am going to a school in new york and therefore i have to buy a new uniform to go to new york'

{p: len(text[:text.find(p)].strip().split()) for p in lst}
# {'new york': 7, 'school': 5, 'new': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `count` and `index`:

```
lst = ['new york', 'school', 'new']
text = 'i am going to a school in new york and therefore i have to buy a new uniform to go to new york'

for x in lst:
    print(f"{x} = {text.count(' ', 0, text.index(x))}")

# new york = 7
# school = 5                                                   
# new = 7
```

`count` counts whitespaces in `text` from start till you meet the first appearance of phrase which is same as the number of words preceding that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['new york', 'school', 'new']
text = 'i am going to a school in new york and therefore i have to buy a new uniform to go to new york'
```

This will give you the string whose count you are searching and count of string

```
for x in lst:
    print(x +": "+str(len(text[0:text.index(x)].split(' ')) -1))
```